# Zend Pdf round corners in rectangle section

Tags: pdf, zend-framework, magento2.4.0

I wrote the below code to show rectangle in pdf file

```
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.92)); 
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.92));
        $page->drawRectangle($x, $oldY+20, ($pageWidth/2)-50, $this->y-10);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
```

AND Output is [image]

But I need round corners in rectangle how can I do this in Magento 2 Zend pdf.I wanna output like this

Expected output: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use some tricky like

```
// draw rounded rectangle like
$page->drawRoundedRectangle($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $radius);
// draw classic rectangle over rounded rectangle
$page->drawRectangle($x1 - 15, $y1, $x2, $y2, $radius);
```